# Get list of Gradle tasks in type-safe way

Tags: gradle, groovy

I need to configure all tasks of type `FindBugs` with some custom configuration.

Right now I'm doing it as follows:

```
[findbugsMain as FindBugs, findbugsTest as FindBugs].each {
    ... // 'it' has now inferred 'FindBugs' type
}
```

However, I'm limited to the tasks I explicitly know and I need to perform nasty casts.

**Is it possible to get list of all tasks of some particular type in some type-safe or compile-static friendly manner?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
tasks.withType(FindBugs)
```